# When a manifold is a subset of a sphere?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a smooth connected 2-dimensional manifold.
I need to show that TFAE

1) for any smooth $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow M$  we have $\int_{\gamma} xdx + ydy + zdz = 0$
2) $M$ is a subset of a 2-dimensional sphere of some radius.

**attempt**:
denote $\omega=xdx+ydy+zdz$

Assume 1) and let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow M$ so 
$\int_{\gamma}\omega = 0$ implies $\int_0^1 \langle \gamma (t),\dot{\gamma} (t)\rangle dt =0$.
 
I know from basic ODE, that such curves form circles, but I don't know how to formalize it.

For the other direction I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Can you write $\omega=df$ for some $f$?

Edit: Let $f=r^2/2$; Stokes' theorem says $\int_\gamma\omega=\int_{\partial\gamma} f=f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))$, which is zero iff both endpoints are at the same radius. Then mumble something about connectedness and get the quantifiers in the right order, and you're done!

Comment: Of course, $f = \frac{x^2 + y^2 +z^2 +const}{2}$, and of course, the pre-image $f^{-1}(0)$ is a subset of some sphere. But I can't see how to use this to say $M \subset f^{-1}(0)$

Comment: Right, now can you use that to evaluate the integral?

Comment: If it's legal to say that $\int_{\gamma} \omega = f(\gamma)$ then yes. But is it?

I mean, this transitions are scary in high dimensions

Comment: Stokes' theorem says $\int_\gamma\omega=\int_{\partial\gamma} f=f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))$. Which is zero iff both endpoints are at the same radius.

Comment: If you could add your last comment to the answer it'll be great!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No prob... done!